# Why Validator show in Validator and Validator Summary

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a validator and a validationsummery on my page.

When it happens, that the page is not valid, the text appears on the validator itself and in the validation summary.

What do im wrong?

```
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationGroup="Register" CssClass="validator" ForeColor="black" 
                                    ControlToValidate="txtRegisterEmail" ID="valMail" runat="server" 
                                    ValidationExpression=".*@.*\.(com|net|org|edu|mil|at?|de?|ch?|uk?)$" 
                                    ErrorMessage="Bitte geben Sie eine gültige EMail-Adresse ein." 
                                     EnableClientScript="false" 
                                    Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>


 <asp:LinkButton CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="Register" ID="linkRegister" CssClass="linkWhite" runat="server" 
                                    onclick="linkRegister_Click">Jetzt Registrieren</asp:LinkButton><br />
                                    <br />
                                <asp:ValidationSummary ValidationGroup="Register" ID="sumRegister" runat="server" 
                                HeaderText="Folgende Fehler sind aufgetreten:"  CssClass="validator" 
                                ShowSummary="true" DisplayMode="BulletList" />
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's by design, you're not doing anything wrong.

If you want the validation message to appear only in the summary, you can set the [Display](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.display.aspx) property of your validator control to `None`.

If you don't want the message to appear in the summary, you can use the [ValidationGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.validationsummary.validationgroup.aspx) property to give different validation group names to your `ValidationSummary` control and your validator control.

Answer (score 1):

If you do this (notice the asterisk after the `"dynamic">`):

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
    ValidationGroup="Register" CssClass="validator" ForeColor="black" 
    ControlToValidate="txtRegisterEmail" ID="valMail" runat="server" 
    ValidationExpression=".*@.*\.(com|net|org|edu|mil|at?|de?|ch?|uk?)$" 
    ErrorMessage="Bitte geben Sie eine gültige EMail-Adresse ein." 
    EnableClientScript="false" 
    Display="Dynamic">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

You will get a little asterisk next any invalid fields, and then the error message will appear in the validation summary. In my apps I find it helpful to tag the fields with a little (red) asterisk, and then have the user look 'below', or wherever you summary is, for the list of validation errors.